# EditText with a permanent hint in Java

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` with some information in it. When there is no information,
I'm displaying a caption using `setHint()`.

```
final EditText info = new EditText(activity);
if (data.getinfo() != null && !data.getAddress().trim().equals("")) {
    info.setText(data.getinfo());
} else {
    info.setHint(R.string.info);
}
```

I want to show that caption even if the `EditText` has info, the info should be below the caption.

I tried using `setText()`. But that didn't work either.

```
if (condition) {
    info.setText(R.string.info);
    info.setText(data.getinfo());
} else {
    info.setHint(R.string.info);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within a `RelativeLayout`, use a `TextView` as an overlay `View` on top of your `EditText`. Use appropriate colors, size for the font to achieve the effect you are looking for.

Here is a hint

```
<RelativeLayout …>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/name" 
        android:layoutWidth="match_parent"
        android:layoutHeight="wrap_content" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/name_hint" 
        android:layoutWidth="wrap_content"
        android:layoutHeight="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/name" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is just a starting point, you can adjust the height of your `EditText`, position your `TextView`, change its `gravity`, etc., to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do it through xml tag which you've added in your UI layout.

Comment: @rocker..there is no xml file for this..created the layout in java