# Android: Edittext with hint

Tags: android

Hi i have a edittext with hint ..what iam trying to implement is whenever i am getting the info into the Edittext or when the user types into the edittext..the hint should stay and text user types should start below or beside hint...**can we make the hint permanent?**.or is there any way we can implement ..any suggestion is appreciated

```
EditText address = new EditText(activity);

                if (data.getAddress() != null
                        && !data.getAddress().trim().equals("")) {

                    address.setText(data.getAddress());
                } else {
                    address.setHint(R.string.address);
                }
```

Comment: why you want a permanent hint. you could use a text view along with the editext to show the hint text.

Comment: This is duplicate of your own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13289447/450534

Comment: @ SahilMahajanMj :from the above code how to use textview with edittext..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant directly set a permanent hint for the editext . Instead you could use a text view along with the editext to show the hint text and make the background of both as transparent and give your own background to the layout holding both the text view and the edit text. It will create a view of editext with a permanent hint.

This [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135075/1626878) will help you.

Comment: @teekib You should start using xml as it really makes your life easier when programming native.

Comment: dont you have a main.xml file.? so where are you showing your edit text then.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Background image of edit text.